# Task Scheduler to send Email through Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation, windows-xp

So basically I already have a batch script that would log some information in a text file. The thing is I want to have it send an email with the results. I was wondering if there is a way to do it using the task scheduler or something of the sort. I just want this thing to be automated without the use of any other software. I only want to use what is built in with the OS.

Comment: Ouch. I'm not aware of a native utility that would allow you to send an email using batch. If you want strictly native commands then I think you will have to go outside the world of batch and use something like VScript or JScript. Here is a link demonstrating a [VBS solution in the 2nd listed option](http://www.petri.co.il/send_mail_from_script.htm)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a VBScript... everything is built in and it is pretty darn easy.

Here is a write up:  http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm
Another one:  http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/enterprise/mail/

The easiest thing would be to attach your file as an attachment whose name doesn't change.  So your batch would like something like (not tested)

```
.... your existing stuff .... > emailAttach.txt
cscript.exe theEmailSendingScript.vbs
del /f emailAttach.txt
```

That way the timer can kick this off and reuse the same filename.  The vbscript can attach emailAttach.txt and it was always be the new file.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I really want to avoid using anything outside of what is already there. I want to avoid downloading any extra program.

Comment: cscript.exe is built in to windows.  there are two vbs script runners that are built in cscript & wscript.  Both go back to at least windows NT.  Just thought I'd mention this.  I've solved the 'send an email' from a timer problem a few times and have settled on vbscript.  You can also use jscript, but there are less examples on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

A couple solutions for future readers:

- Task Scheduler can now send email as an action in a Task.  I believe the feature was added to Windows Server 2008.
- I have used blat.exe in batch files for years.  Very flexible tool [found here](http://www.blat.net/)
- Powershell's [Send-MailMessage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) cmdlet